# Command for finding file size of imported csv file in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have imported 3 csv files in my sqlite database.Is there a way to check the size of imported csv files through sql queries?

Comment: What do you mean with "size"? Number of rows? Values? Bytes?

Comment: File size in Bytes